# How to create static function outside a component in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

While I was reading article [Persistent Layout Patterns in Next.js](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/), there is a part that I can't get my head around.

```
// /pages/account-settings/basic-information.js
import SiteLayout from '../../components/SiteLayout'
import AccountSettingsLayout from '../../components/AccountSettingsLayout'

const AccountSettingsBasicInformation = () => <div>{/* ... */}</div>

AccountSettingsBasicInformation.getLayout = page => (
  <SiteLayout>
    <AccountSettingsLayout>{page}</AccountSettingsLayout>
  </SiteLayout>
)

export default AccountSettingsBasicInformation
```

At **Option 4**, static function getLayout is added to **AccountSettingsBasicInformation**.

However **AccountSettingsBasicInformation** is a component not an object.

Is it possible to add static function in a component like this way?

Also I created Test component to test it but I got the typescript error saying

**Property 'hello' does not exist on type 'FC'.**

```
interface ITestProps {
  hello: () => void;
}

const Test: React.FC<ITestProps> = () => {
  return <TestFilter />;
};

Test.hello = () => { <div> this is a test </div> } // Test.hello occurs the error

export default Test;
```

I declared hello type at ITestProps but why I got the error?

Answer (score 0):

anything other than basic types is object, including es6 classes and function.

but typescript has the ability to enforce what properties an object has,

so you can say `AccountSettingsBasicInformation.getLayout` because AccountSettingsBasicInformation has no type declaration, typescript considers it as any(which includes basic types and object with any properties)

but you declared `Test` as `React.FC<ITestProps>` so typescript enforces its properties to be same as `React.FC<ITestProps>`, so it prints out an error